# xsl xml web page not parsing

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The following xsl document is not parsing when I try to load the webpage. I am very new at this sort of stuff, and I can't find the bug. I used google chrome web developer tools, but it did not find any errors. 
What am I doing wrong and why wont this document parse?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<?xsl-stylesheet type =
  "text/xsl"xmlns:xsl="http://district.bluegrass.kctcs.edu/bwells0086/bookstore.xml"?>
  <xsl:output method = "html">
  <?xsl-template match="Book"?>

        <html>
        <body>
        <table border = "3" bgcolor= "lightgreen">
        <tr>
                <th>Book Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Selling Price</th>
                <th>Publication Year</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl-for-each select= "BookTitle/Author/SellingPrice/PublicationYear/
     Publisher">
        <tr>
                <td><xsl-value-of select="BookTitle"/></td>
                <td><xsl-value-of select="Author"/></td>
                <td><xsl-value-of select="SellingPrice"/></td>
                <td><xsl-value-of select="PublicationYear"/></td>
                <td><xsl-value-of select="Publisher"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl-for-each>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
</xsl-stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have not accepted nor commented on any answers given to you before? Get familiar with SO habits...

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that this is not an XML document, and thus cannot be an XSLT stylesheet.  In addition, there are a number of problems in the usage of various constructs.

Among the problems:

- You have a processing instruction of the form `<?xsl-stylesheet ... ?>`, but there is no standard meaning for such a processing instruction.
- You have an end-tag for an element named `xsl-stylesheet` but no start-tag for such an element.
- The file you show has no elements in the XSL namespace, only elements in no namespace whose local names begin `xsl-` -- these are not XSL elements.

It would probably be wise to invest some time in learning the basics of XML and acquiring tools which can help you with them.  You will want a parser which can tell you whether a sequence of characters is a well-formed XML document or not.  (After you use such a tool for a day or two, you will start to need it less, and be able to identify well-formedness issues by eye.  But until then, and even after, there is no substitute for running a parser over your data.)  You will want to try to understand XML namespaces, or at least learn to live with them; you will want to learn how your parser tells you that there are namespace problems in a document.  And then you will be in a position to start learning XSLT.

Good luck!